Testing replace token with simple yaml file
I have done Testing “replacement token” test on simple yaml file with MS agent. which is YAML below: I have used MS agent
all tasks succeeded but not sure why it is not replaced and showing as test02 it is in last task which “print after file replace”''
rigger:

main
pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:

name: TestSetting
default: testSet01
values:
testSet01
testSet02
testSet03
stages:

stage: A
jobs:

job: A1
steps:
task: Bash@3
displayName: 'Set variable'
inputs:
targetType: inline
script: |
echo 'The selected TestSetting is ${{ parameters. TestSetting }}.'
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;] ${{ parameters. TestSetting }}"
task: Bash@3
displayName: 'Print file before replace'
inputs:
targetType: inline
script: 'cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appsettings.json'

task: Bash@3
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: 'echo $(TestSetting_Name)'

task: Bash@3
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: 'cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appsettings.json'

task: replacetokens@6
inputs:
root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
sources: 'appsettings.json'

task: Bash@3
displayName: 'Print file after replace'
inputs:
targetType: inline
script: 'cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appsettings.json'

Below is the image of the file location where it has to be replaced:
enter image description here
Please suggest, what could be the wrong in the above
I have tried couple of options using different directory paths and different file names but nothing worked

Could you please fix the yaml code?

Add tokenPattern: 'doublebraces' to your replacetokens@6 task. Refer to the following yaml.
parameters:
- name: TestSetting
  default: testSet01
  type: string
  values:
  - testSet01
  - testSet02
  - testSet03

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Set variable'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo ${{ parameters. TestSetting }}
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;]${{ parameters. TestSetting }}"
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print file before replace'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appsettings.json'
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        sources: 'appsettings.json'
        tokenPattern: 'doublebraces'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print file after replace'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appsettings.json'

Checking the logs, it works fine.


so we no need to use below task? am I correct?   - task: Bash@3
displayName: 'Set variable'
inputs:
targetType: inline
script: |
echo 'The selected TestSetting is ${{ parameters.TestSetting }}.'
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;]${{ parameters.TestSetting }}"
I can go head with variables:


name: TestSettings_Name
value: ${{ parameters.TestSetting }}   ?


Fixing the typo
You have a typo - you're setting the TestSettings_Name variable, but you're trying to use echo $(TestSetting_Name) - the s letter is missing.
Improving the code
Instead of setting a variable like this:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;] ${{ parameters. TestSetting }}"

Just declare a variable at the pipeline or job level - example:
parameters:
  - name: TestSetting
    type: string
    default: testSet01
    values:
      - testSet01
      - testSet02
      - testSet03

variables:
  - name: TestSettings_Name
    value: ${{ parameters.TestSetting }}

# using the variable
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo $(TestSettings_Name)'

